# How to %time each interaction of a function?

Tags: python, function

I have a function, Func(n), that is only a function of a natural number n,
for example:

```
import numpy as np
Func = lambda n: np.sin(n**2)
```

When I make

```
%time Func = [Func(n) for n in np.arange(100)]
Wall time: 260 µs
```

this gives me the *total* time it took the function `Func(n)` to calculate the first value of `n=0` (`Func(0)`) until to the final value of `n=100` (`Func(100)`) but not the time of *each* interaction. *A priori*, if the function `Func(n)` were much more complicated than the simple `np.sin(n**2)` then the time of computation of `Func(n)` for `n=0` or `n=1` can be considerably differente for the time of computation of `Func(n)` for `n=100` or `n=10000`. Then I wonder if there is a manner of make `%time` interactively, inside a loop, for example:

```
for n in np.arange(100):
    print('n =',n)
    %time Func = [Func(n)]
```

but this got me the result only of the first interaction, that is, the time that the program  took to calculate `Func(0)`, and after give me the following error message:

```
n = 0
Wall time: 25.3 µs
n = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<timed exec> in <module>

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

May be this is simple but I never dealt with the calculation of time a program. How can I compute the this time for each iteration ?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using list comprehensions with NumPy in the first place - `Func(np.arange(100))` would run a lot faster. Also, don't reuse the `Func` name, and don't name your variables and functions in uppercase. Uppercase is for classes.

Comment: What do you want to do with this data? Plot it? Do you want to see the time complexity? If so, can we make the range more-sparse/logarithmic?

Comment: Yes!!. In practice I have a function (involving integrals of Spherical Bessel function `jn`) that is very much more complicated than `sin(n**2)` and my function for j_1000(x) is much more complicated than this function for j_0(x). So I want know how much time this function took for each iteration. Is linear? is logarithmic? Maybe a graphic can said...

Comment: `Func(np.arange(100)` is indeed faster, as it would utilise the C bindings of numpy, if I am not mistaken.However, this is not the point. If I understood this right, @stlevel0 wants to use this for a function of any complexity that might perform differently given the provided parameter. `sin(x**2)` is just an example

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it seems that you want to time this for function complexity. I've literally thrown together an example where you can specify range of inputs that you want to test your function for, how many repeats you want at each point, and a plot of mean execution time with standard deviation.

I don't *think* you can make use of IPython magic `%time` or `%timeit` to get this level of data back out to plot. Again, it's a rough guide.

```
import time
import statistics

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(n, repeats=10):
    all_times = []

    for x in range(repeats):
        start = time.time()
        res = [x ** 10000 for x in range(n)] # The time-consuming computation
        duration = time.time() - start
        all_times.append(duration)

    stdev = statistics.stdev(all_times)
    return statistics.mean(all_times), stdev


def make_plot(data):
    x = [item[0] for item in data]
    y = [item[1] for item in data]
    stdev = [item[2] for item in data]

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.errorbar(x, y, yerr=stdev)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    all_data = []

    # Define your range of inputs to your function 
    for x in range(100):
        y, stdev = func(x)
        all_data.append([x, y, stdev])

    make_plot(all_data)
```

This will give you something like:

[image]

Where the x-axis the the value of n to your function, the y axis is the execution time. You have a mean value, and also error bars for the standard deviation. The example is really quick fast-running, so I'm not so surprised about the spikes in errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `%time` command itself. Your code overwrites `Func` on the first call and changes its type to a list (`[Func(n)]` is a list).

Changing the variable name will fix your issue:

```py
import numpy as np
Func = lambda n: np.sin(n**2)

for n in np.arange(100):
    print('n =',n)
    %time variable = [Func(n)]
    #     ^^^^^^^^ use different variable name than Func
```

Also note that `%time` does the following:

> Time execution of a Python statement or expression

As `[Func(n) for n in np.arange(100)]` is an expression in itself, `%time` will thus return the time it took for the whole expression (i.e. 100 iterations). Your solution using `for` is probably the easiest way to do what you want.

However, `%time` should be replaced by [`%timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) and appropriate options to get a statistically relevant measurement. Using the `-o` option, you could also save the time as a python object e.g. to later plot the time.

Comment: Thanks you very much @JonasDrotleff. I would never figure out that the problem is because of the same variable name. I simply took the first case and tried to generalize.